# How to filter ListBox using Check box list

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, checkboxlist

i have checkbox list and Listbox in asp.net webforms,
Checkbox list is set to take its datascource from N table ,
ListBox is set to take its datasource from P table,
there is many to many relation between p And N tables so  there is a table P_N
Now i want to check on or more of checkboxes and as result the  P in List Box are filtered,  N table consists of (N_Id, N_Name), P Table Consist of (P_ID, P_Name)
and P_N table Consist of (P_ID, N_ID)

Answer (score 0):

You would iterate through your CheckBox list to aquire results to show...

```
var results;

foreach (var i in CheckBoxList.Items)
{
    if (i.Checked == true)
    { // Add selected ID to ListBox
        results += (from c in PTable.All()
                    where c.ID == i.Value // i.Value would be however you're storing the ID in the CheckBoxList
                    select c).ToList();
    }
}

ListBox.DataSource = results;
ListBox.DataBind();
```

Pseudo code of course, but it should get you started.